# Position center of div tag, which width is unknown advanced

Tags: jquery, html, css, center

I have div with no fixed with. I want this div position in the center of screen.

I know how to make this with jquery, but with pure css, I did not find any solution. How do you make this happen with pure css?

Comment: Put you div withing `<center> </center>`

Comment: You really don't want to use a center tag.

Comment: I think this article may be what you need: http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to shrink-wrap the contents of the div (otherwise centring it is a pointless exercise as its width will be the width of the container):

- Set `display: inline-block;` on the div to make it shrink-wrap
- Set `text-align: center;` on the div's parent element to centre the div
- Set `text-align: left;` on the div to override the centring of its inline content that it would inherit from its parent.