# How can I position a DIV in another DIV so the space above the DIV and below it is equal?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="content left"></div>
    <div class="content right">
       <div class="fill">
           <div class="blue">
             xxx <br> xxx
           </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 body, html { height: 100%; }
#outer { position:absolute; margin:5%; bottom:0; top:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden; }
.content { position:absolute; width:50%; height:100%; }
.content.left { background-color:yellow; }
.content.right { background-color:red; left:50%; }
.fill { padding: 2em; background-color: green; height: 100%;}
.blue { background-color: blue; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8gy5/)

How can I make it so the space above and below the blue DIV is the same height?

Comment: I would use percents. Let's say add `.blue { background-color: blue; height: 90%; margin: 5% 0; }`

Comment: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663181/position-absolute-width-unknown-how-to-center-div

Answer (score 2):

The following should work for you:

```
.blue { 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is a good reference for vertically aligning content [Link](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: Only the empty div would be centered with your solution ;)

Comment: The question: "How can I make it so the space above and below the blue DIV is the same height?" Have you read it?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding.  The way I am reading it is that that @Melina would like the blue div vertically centered.

Comment: I think the space above and below should be, let's say, 20px :) That's the same height :)

Comment: How does adding 20px above and below blue center the div?  Perhaps you could provide an example

Comment: Where do you see word "center" in question? :)

Comment: @Melina, I saw you asked why `position: absolute` the reason is the default position is `static` that will force the object to appear where it appears in the document flow.  `absolute` allows the object to be relative to the first position and is needed to use a percentage for `top`

Answer (score 0):

Are ou asking this because you are not seeing what you expected or becuase you don't know how to program it? 
I'm asking this because you forgot to close the "fill" DIV.

if this is not your problem, try assigning the position to absolute.

```
.blue{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you're answer doesn't really make any sense. What I need to do is to have the same amount of vertical space above the blue div as below the blue div. I am not sure why you want it positioned absolute :-(